# How to get coordinates into data frame using over?

Tags: r

I have a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` and a `SpatialPointDataFrame`. I want to extract the values of the polygons to the points. I'm using `over()`

```
values_poly = over(points, polygons)
```

What I get is a `data.frame` like described but how can I know which row was which point?

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like someone else  had more or less the same question.

For my purposes the function worked very well...

[Joining point to polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216840/joining-point-to-polygon)

Sorry for opening a new topic...

Greetings