# What does the error "arguments imply differing number of rows: x, y" mean?

Tags: r, csv, matrix, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot from elements of csv file which looks like this:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4
a,1,0,1,0
b,1,1,0,1
c,0,0,1,0
```

I tried the following code but am receiving an error saying

> Error in data.frame(id = varieties, attr(mat, "row.names"), check.rows = FALSE) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 20

My sample data has 8 columns and 20 rows (excluding header and row names). I tried to look up online and tried to implement a few fixes but the issue still persists. I'd really appreciate any help.

```
mat <- read.csv("trial.csv", header=T, row.names=1)
varieties = names(mat)
df <- data.frame(id=varieties,attr(mat, "row.names"), check.rows= FALSE)
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Can you run the script line-by-line and report the findings? Is it possible to share the file?

Comment: @MylesBaker 'df <- data.frame(id=varieties,attr(mat, "row.names"), check.rows= FALSE)' gives the error.

Comment: This will only work if `mat` is a square matrix (nrows = ncols). What do you want to achieve? Maybe a `list` is better suited for your needs... Or see `cbind.fill` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962267/cbind-a-df-with-an-empty-df-cbind-fill)

Comment: I'd like to create a plot for a rectangular matrix, showing how each element is distributed across the data @EDi

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this `require(reshape2);
mat$id <- rownames(mat);
melt(mat)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your data.frame `mat` is rectangular (n_rows!= n_cols).

Therefore, you cannot make a `data.frame` out of the column- and rownames, because each column in a data.frame must be the same length.

Maybe this suffices your needs:

```
require(reshape2)
mat$id <- rownames(mat) 
melt(mat)
```

Comment: Why exactly is this an issue? I've never had problems with rectangular data frames. Honestly I doubt any of them ever had the same amount of rows as columns.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error message so I went googling a bit I managed to fix it with the following code.

```
df<-data.frame(words = unlist(words))
```

words is a character list.

This just in case somebody else needs the output to be a data frame.

Answer (score 15):

Though this isn't a DIRECT answer to your question, I just encountered a similar problem, and thought I'd mentioned it:

I had an instance where it was instantiating a new (no doubt very inefficent) record for data.frame (a result of recursive searching) and it was giving me the same error.

I had this:

```
return(
  data.frame(
    user_id = gift$email,
    sourced_from_agent_id = gift$source,
    method_used = method,
    given_to = gift$account,
    recurring_subscription_id = NULL,
    notes = notes,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
)
```

turns out... it was the = NULL.  When I switched to = NA, it worked fine.  Just in case anyone else with a similar problem hits THIS post as I did.