# arguments imply differing number of rows with plotting row of dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this

```
        a    b     c     d
row1    1    2     2     3
row2    2    4     5     9
row3    1    4     4     6
```

For each row I want to write a histogram to a page in a pdf. I tried to do it like this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    histogram <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=as.numeric(df[i,]))) +geom_histogram()
    ggsave(filename="output.pdf", plot=histogram)
}
```

However, this gives me the error `arguments imply differing number of rows: 115, 734`. From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26148043/651779 I tried to do

```
df$id <- rownames(df)
df <- melt(df)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  histogram <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=as.numeric(df[i,]))) +geom_histogram()
  ggsave(filename="output.pdf", plot=histogram)
}
```

but this gives me the same error but with a different number `arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 84410`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df2 <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(df[i, ]))
  histogram <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x)) + geom_histogram()
  ggsave(filename = "output.pdf", plot = histogram)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would transpose the data.frame using `t` and then plot like this:

```
#transpose df
df <- data.frame(t(df))

#notice aes_string in order for i to be the name as character
for (i in names(df)){
  histogram <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=i)) + geom_histogram()
  ggsave(filename="output.pdf", plot=histogram)
}
```