# Augment with newdata works with one model fails with another

Tags: r, broom

I'm missing something so fundamental here -- why does augment work with
one model but not another?

```
data(iris)
library(broom)

iris$cSepal.Length <- scale(iris$Sepal.Length, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
nd <- expand.grid(Sepal.Length = seq(4, 8, 0.1), Species = factor(levels(iris$Species)))
nd$cSepal.Length <- nd$Sepal.Length - mean(iris$Sepal.Length)

m0 <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * Species, data = iris)
pred.0 <- augment(m0, newdata = nd)
m1 <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ cSepal.Length * Species, data = iris)
pred.1 <- augment(m1, newdata = nd)

## Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE): arguments imply differing number of rows: 123, 150

sessionInfo()

## R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 10586)
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
## [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
## [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] broom_0.4.1         RevoUtilsMath_8.0.3
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] Rcpp_0.12.6      knitr_1.11       magrittr_1.5     mnormt_1.5-4    
##  [5] lattice_0.20-33  R6_2.1.2         stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.4      
##  [9] dplyr_0.5.0      tools_3.3.1      parallel_3.3.1   grid_3.3.1      
## [13] nlme_3.1-128     psych_1.6.6      DBI_0.4-1        htmltools_0.2.6 
## [17] yaml_2.1.13      assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.8     tibble_1.1      
## [21] reshape2_1.4.1   formatR_1.4      tidyr_0.5.1      evaluate_0.7.2  
## [25] rmarkdown_0.9.5  stringi_1.1.1    RevoUtils_10.0.1
```

Comment: `> nrow(iris); [1] 150`. `> nrow(nd); [1] 123` ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/26148043/2381339 Seems two tables/dfs are joined here mabye ?

Comment: Yes but why does it work with m0 and not with m1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with `scale()`. It is returning a matrix and not a vector. Assigning the matrix into the the data.frame is causing problems. You are using `scale()` to create `iris$cSepal.Length` but are using `x-mean(x)` to create `nd$cSepal.Length`. This creates two different data types which causes problems during the predictions of the two different models when you are using the `cSepal.Length` column.

It would be best if you used the same centering method each time you create the column. If you just did

```
iris$cSepal.Length <- iris$Sepal.Length - mean(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

everything will work.