# R Code Error - "arguments imply differing number of rows"

Tags: r

I am getting the error : arguments imply differing number of rows when inserting a return code.

```
gdf_Google_Close <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(cta5Data$ï..Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), 
                                Close = cta5Data$Google.Close)
gdf_Amazon_Close <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(cta5Data$ï..Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), 
                               Close = cta5Data$Amazon.Close)
base_Close <- ggplot(gdf_Google_Close,aes(Date,Close)) +
                  geom_line(aes(color="Google")) +
                  geom_line(data=gdf_Amazon_Close, aes(color="Amazon")) +
                  labs(color="Close")

gdf_Google_Return <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(cta5Data$ï..Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), 
                                Return = cta5Data$Google.Return)

Error in data.frame(Date = as.Date(cta5Data$ï..Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 253, 0
```

Comment: Seems your data frame is not a square matrix when the number of columns equals to the number of rows. Have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147558/what-does-the-error-arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows-x-y-mean), might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome t stack overflow. Please try to provide some reproducible data. Without `cdta5Data` it will be impossible to know what is causing your error.